# JavaScript - how to remove `options` by its `value`

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu with products similiar like this

```
<select class="fruits" >
  <option value="1" >Oranges</option> 
  <option value="2" >Bananes</option> 
  <option value="3" >Apples</option> 
</select>
```

I need to remove `options` by its `value`. How to do that ?
Pure JavaScript please.

EDIT : I know that I need to use `element.removeChild(child)` method. But how to reference child by its `value`. Thats my point.

EDIT 2 : I use the script of `zdrohn` below and it works. Because I have several `fruits` dropdowns with the same collection I need to iterate trough all dropdowns and delete it from all dropdowns. This is my code now :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var id = 3;
            var el= document.getElementsByClassName("fruits");
                for (i=0;i<el.length;i++) {
                    for(var n = 0; n < el[i].length; n++) {
                        if(el[i][n].value == id) {
                            el[i][n].remove();
                        }
                }

 </script>
```

Though it works I wonder about that I do not need to use the `parent.removeChild()` method. How comes ?

P.S. I wonder that peole vote this question down. As the response shows their are several solutions. Though not all are sufficiantly explained.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Of course. I know that I need to use element.removeChild(child). But how to reference a particular option by its value. Thats the point.

Comment: `sel.value=2;sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<select class="fruits" >
  <option value="1" >Oranges</option> 
  <option value="2" >Bananas</option> 
  <option value="3" >Apples</option> 
</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var valueToRemove = 1;
 
var select = document.getElementsByClassName('fruits');

for(var i = 0; i < select[0].length; i++) {
 if(select[0][i].value == valueToRemove) {
  select[0][i].remove();
 }
}



</script>
```

Edit:

```html
<select class="fruits" >
  <option value="1">Oranges</option> 
  <option value="2">Bananas</option> 
  <option value="3">Apples</option> 
</select>

<br>

<label>Input value to delete</label><input type='text' id='delete_value'>
<button onclick='remove(document.getElementById("delete_value").value)'>Delete</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>




function remove(item) {
 var valueToRemove = item;
 
 var select = document.getElementsByClassName('fruits');


 for(var i = 0; i < select[0].length; i++) {
  if(select[0][i].value == valueToRemove) {
   select[0][i].remove();
  }
 }

}



</script>
```

Comment: @Ben I just forgot to remove it before posting the answer

Comment: `select[0]` is not an array or node list. I think you mean `select[0].childNodes`. But this is a "live" collection, so when you remove an option the indexes of all the following options moves down, and then you'll skip the next option in the loop.

Comment: developer.mozilla.org describes a HTMLCollection as an `array-like object`. So `select[0]` is an `element` at the position `[0]`. Or what means `select[0]`in detail ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet to play with.

The code removes the `option` with *value = 3*

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var optionToDelete = document.querySelector("select.fruits > option[value='3']");
  optionToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(optionToDelete);
}
```

```html
<select class="fruits">
  <option value="1">Oranges</option>
  <option value="2">Bananes</option>
  <option value="3">Apples</option>
</select>
```

---

**EDIT**: Based on the updated question - *I have several fruits drop-downs*.

We could make use of [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all matching elements and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to apply the desired *logic* on each element in the selected list.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var optionsToDelete = document.querySelectorAll("select.fruits > option[value='3']");

  optionsToDelete.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<select class="fruits">
  <option value="1">Oranges</option>
  <option value="2">Bananes</option>
  <option value="3">Apples</option>
</select>

<select class="fruits">
  <option value="1">Seville oranges</option>
  <option value="2">Burro Bananes</option>
  <option value="3">Baldwin Apples</option>
</select>

<select class="fruits">
  <option value="1">Bergamot oranges</option>
  <option value="2">Red Bananes</option>
  <option value="3">Gravenstein Apples</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the desired option by using `document.querySelector()` and a selector of [this form](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)

A more complete list of selectors can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/L2cu79f6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.evaluate( '//option[@value="1"]' ,document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null ).singleNodeValue;
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

Comment: Document.evaluate finds things using xpath